# passing string as a variable name

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have the following method:

```
string fieldName = "dateAdded";

public void assignData(IEnumerable<object> enumerable) {
  foreach (dynamic customData in enumerable) {
    try { 

      // what I need: if(customData.[fieldName] == DateTime.Now)
      if(customData.dateAdded == DateTime.Now) 
          customData.dateAdded = newValue;
      }

    } catch { 

    }
  }
}
```

I need to pass a field name and check if it matches DateTime.Now. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: where could you pass the field name in your method? Is it a **field** or a **property**?

Comment: This seems like a weird place to use dynamic, why is your IEnumerable returning `object` instead of the class or a interface. Also the capturing of the exception and doing nothing looks like bad coding practice, I would refactor this if possible.

Comment: what does `customData` holds?

Comment: There should be `var` instead of `dynamic`

Comment: @KingKing not sure what you mean. It's DateTime dateAdded. I need something like customData["dateAdded"], only not with arrays. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use reflection for this:

```
var value = customData.GetType().GetField(fieldName).GetValue(customData);

if (value as DateTime? == DateTime.Now)
{
   //...
```

You may need to use `GetProperty` instead of `GetField` if it is actually a property, not a field.  You also probably want to verify that the field/property exists before accessing it as well.

Of course if possible you shouldn't be relying on this.  It would be best if, instead of passing in `IEnumerable<object>` you could use a function such as this:

```
public void assignData<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable
    , Func<TSource, DateTime> getter, Action<TSource, DateTime> setter)
{
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        if (getter(item) == DateTime.Now)
            setter(item, newvalue);
    }
}
```

Then the caller can simply provide the function needed to get/set the value.  It could be called like this:

```
assignData(list, item => item.dateAdded
   , (item, newDate) => item.dateAdded = newDate);
```

Comment: I guess the `fieldName` is also `public`, otherwise, it fails.

Comment: @KingKing Sure.  If you need to look at private values then you could add the appropriate parameter to `GetField`.  Hopefully that's not needed though.

Comment: @Servy can you tell me what does the '?' mean in the if statement?

Comment: @Servy I'm getting 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference' on 'var value = ..'

Comment: @user2320462 The question mark makes the datetime nullable.  `as` needs to be able to set the value to `null` if it cannot be properly cast.  If you're getting that error then it means you have a null item in your sequence.  You'll need to either remove `null` items first, or check for `null` in this loop and skip those items.